# how would i put a whole bunch of float numbers into a list and then find the lowest common multiple of all the numbers?

Tags: list, python-3.x, lcm

how would i put a whole bunch of float numbers into a list and then find the lowest common multiple of all the numbers?

My problem is that i have a text file with info on solar systems and i have isolated the value for the period of revolution for each planet and their moons and i would like to find the LCM for all the periods. The problem is the periods are all in floats not integers and I can't make a list of them. Also I'm having trouble with developing my LCM equation.. any help would be greatly appreciated

Jordan

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you make a list of floats? Whats the code you're using?
`x = [2.2, 3.3, 6.9]` works fine for me..

What do you mean by lowest common multiple of two floats? There are several intepretations of this. Look at the wiki article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple